# Unable to set custom background color in jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using the following code to set alternate background row color in a jTable :

```
table = new JTable(model);
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer()
{//alternate background color for rows
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,  boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if (!isSelected)
           c.setBackground(row % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : Color.lightGray);
        return c;
    };
});
```

And it works.
However I would like to use a custom color say rgb (242,242,242) in place of lightGray as the alternate color, but when doing:

```
final Color alternateColor = new Color (242,242,242);
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer()
{//alternate background color for rows
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,    boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if (!isSelected)
           c.setBackground(row % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : alternateColor);
        return c;
    };
});
```

the alternate color is completely ignored and all rows have white background. It looks like this method works only with colors which belong to the Color enum. How comes?

Here is a complete working example followed by the resulting screen :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test extends JFrame
{
 private JTable             table               = null;
 private Object[]           columnTitle = { "Column1", "Column2", "Column3" };  
 private Object[][]         data                = null;
 private DefaultTableModel  model               = null;
 private JPanel             panel               = null;
 private JScrollPane        scroller            = null;

 public Test()
    {
        super();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel = new JPanel();
        scroller=new JScrollPane();
        data = new Object[3][3];

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
                for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
                    {
                        data [i][j]="Test";
                    }
            }

        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnTitle);
        table = new JTable(model);
        final Color alternateColor=new Color(242,242,242);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer()
        {//alternate background color for rows
                    @Override
                    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                            boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
                        {
                            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                            if ( !isSelected )
                                c.setBackground(row % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : alternateColor);
                            return c;
                        };
                });

        scroller.setViewportView(table);
        panel.add(scroller);
        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
                {
                    Test test = new Test();
                    test.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    test.pack();
                    test.setVisible(true);
                    test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

And here is the screen with Color.lightGray :
[image]

Comment: Nope, works fine for me. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Well if it works for you, it is probably related to the LAF I am using which is Weblaf. I do not see any other possible reason...

Comment: But the first example works with weblaf?

Comment: Yes the one with "Color.lightGray" works fine.

Comment: Nope, works fine for with WebLaf as well...

Comment: Well that's driving me crazy. Will test further with a small example and will let know.

Comment: And as you say it has nothing to do with weblaf as the running example uses Nimbus.

Comment: [Light Gray is not the same as 242,242,242](http://www.colorcombos.com/colors/F2F2F2). Your first result looks correct

Comment: [`public final static Color lightGray = new Color(192, 192, 192);`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/awt/Color.java#Color)

Comment: Yes you are right peeskillet. The difference with white is really difficult to see but I have tried with darker tones and it works. Stayed too long staring at the screen I suppose :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me...

[image: Test]

```
import com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTable();
    }

    public TestTable() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                WebLookAndFeel.install();

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Test"}, 10);
                JTable table = new JTable(model);
                final Color alternateColor = new Color(255, 0, 255);
                table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {//alternate background color for rows
                    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                        if (!isSelected) {
                            c.setBackground(row % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : alternateColor);
                        }
                        return c;
                    }
                });
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

It's possible that some other rendering has taken oven, that the table your setting the renderer to isn't the one that's on the screen...so many other factors that a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem would elimnate...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have edited the post with a runnable example and a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry for the disturbance and thank you for your help @MadProgrammer. Finally it appears the problem was related to my eye strain not to the code ;)

Answer (score 2):

The approach of overriding the renderer only works if you have data (ie. String) that uses the default renderer in all your columns. What if you have Date or Number data in your table which require different renderers?

In this case check out [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for a solution that works for all data types.

Or maybe you can use:

```
UIManager.put("Table.alternateRowColor", Color.YELLOW);
```

Don't know if this property works on all LAF's.

Comment: Thank you for the information camickr ! However, as mentioned in the comment above : after several tries this proved to be a bug located between the chair and the screen and not related to code after all ;))

Comment: @Zek101, I understand. I was just trying to show more flexible solutions either for you or others that read this.